# How do I get redshift to start with my computer?

Tags: startup-applications

I have installed `Redshift` on my computer and it works fine with the command `gtk-redshift`.

However, it would not start up automatically when using the same command in startup applications.

How do I set it to automatically start?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a known bug [#868904](https://bugs.launchpad.net/redshift/+bug/868904) that stops Redshift starting automatically in 11.10 due to geoclue conflicts on startup.

See [Comment #17](https://bugs.launchpad.net/redshift/+bug/868904/comments/17) on the bug report for a possible solution of setting the location permanently on start up.

> > 1) Use http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html or any other service to find
> >     your latitude/longitude
> >
> > 2) Adjust the startup command of redshift to:
> >     `gtk-redshift -l <latitude>:<longitude>`
> >
> > Example of latitude/longitude of Amsterdam for redshift: gtk-redshift -l 52.37:4.9

It is reportedly fixed in the package 1.7-1ubuntu2 but the Launchpad homepage for the project lists only 1.7-0ubuntu1 built 35 weeks ago.

You could try downloading direct from their [website](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) to see if it fixes the issue with a later version.

Comment: would it start if I used the GNOME-clock method?

Comment: I'm not sure, you could try it but the steps outlined above apparently work..

Comment: I've now tried it with both the gnome-clock and manual methods, and it won't start on either

Comment: Well if you have tried the method above and it does not work I'm out of suggestions. As I said this is a bug in Redshift so you may well just have to wait for it to be resolved by the Redshift developer.

Comment: This problem also occurs with 14.04 and your second option worked well for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Create a file named `redshift.conf` in `~/.config` and add your co-ordinates to it. It should end up looking something [like this](http://jonls.dk/2010/10/redshift-1-6-released/):

```
[redshift]
location-provider=manual
[manual]
lat=55.0
lon=12.0
```

Comment: This worked for me with `redshift-gtk` v1.7 (set to autostart) on Trusty.

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest two ways:

1. Using crontab
2. Using upstart

**CRONTAB**

Crontab is a program that is running all the time. It has a list with programs and scripts and the exact dates or intervals that they should run. Crontab is used a lot by system administrators for making backups and automating tasks.

To see the list with the programs you can type

```
crontab -l
```

To edit the list type

```
crontab -e
```

Add this line in the end, to boot redshift whenever computer starts up

```
@reboot export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /usr/bin/redshift -l 56.20:16.35
```

where 56.20:16.35 is the `LATITUDE:LONGITUTE` of your location.
Save and reboot.

**UPSTART**

Upstart is a program that amongst other things, looks in specific folders at bootup for scripts to be run. So we can just add our program in there to have it run in every booutup. Upstart is more low-level than crontab and you need root privileges.

To add redshift you simply have to edit `/etc/rc.local` file. Add the path to redshift **before** the `exit` in the file or else it won't run. You can find the path by typing `whereis redshift`. The file should look similar to this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
pcscd
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/usr/bin/redshift

exit 0
```

Save and reboot.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 14.04, neither approach works. In particular with the crontab approach, I can see in `syslog` that the command is run, there is no error message, but the process is gone by the time login screen comes up. (That is, there is no visual effect of Redshift running, and after login I can confirm that there is indeed no redshift process running.)

Comment: [This post](http://superuser.com/a/713718/74934) suggests that both the approaches you propose are doomed to fail. Did you actually confirm that they work (in more than one setup)? For instance, I have checked that $DISPLAY is sometimes `:0` and sometimes `:0.0` for me, so how can I hardcode a value?

Comment: Should have checked whether this actually works before upvoting. As @Raphael 's comment says, this doesn't work at all. Now I can't remove my upvote! 

Answer (score 4):

Connect your computer to internet and run `gtk-redshift` in Terminal.

The output will be:

```
maez@maez:~$ gtk-redshift
Trying location provider `geoclue'...
Started Geoclue provider `Geoclue Master'.
Using provider `geoclue'.

** (process:3541): WARNING **: Could not get location, 3 retries left.

According to the geoclue provider we're at: 18.98, 72.83
Using method `randr'.
```

Once you get your Latitude and Longitude from above, Go ahead and Edit autostart config file for Redshift, which is found in "~/.config/autostart/"

```
maez@maez:~$ cd .config/autostart/
maez@maez:~/.config/autostart$ gedit redshift-gtk.desktop
```

In gedit window add "-l 18.98:72.83" next to "Exec=redshift-gtk"

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Color temperature adjustment tool
StartupNotify=true
Exec=redshift-gtk -l 18.98:72.83
Terminal=false
GenericName=Color temperature adjustment
Version=1.0
Categories=Utility;
Hidden=false
Icon=redshift
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Redshift
```

where **18.98:72.83** is your LATITUDE:LONGITUTE

Save this file and Reboot.

Comment: One can just `cp /usr/share/applications/redshift.desktop ~/.config/autostart/`

Answer (score 1):

Antoher workaround ([comment #53](https://bugs.launchpad.net/redshift/+bug/868904/comments/53)) is to install `geoclue-hostip`.

Even though on my setup (Ubuntu 13.04) the manual position workaround works, and I prefer it anyway because it allows me to indicate the location more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an old question, but for those who might stumble upon it, a possible solution may simply be by [removing geoclue and --if it doesn't already exist-- installing geoclue-2.0](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/158)

Something like: `apt remove geoclue && apt install geoclue-2.0`

Logout and log back in to see the changes.

p.s. if the colors are not telling, you can check whether redshift is running using the `ps` command. e.g. `ps aux | grep redshift`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

1. create a config file, e.g. `/etc/redshift.conf`

   ```
   [redshift]
   location-provider=manual

   [manual]
   lat=xx.xxx
   lon=yy.yyy
   ```
2. create a script that calls this file, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/redshift.sh` (`chmod 755` afterwards)

   ```
   redshift -c  /etc/redshift.conf &
   ```
3. call this whenever the display manager starts. For LightDM, this would be a file at `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/90-redshift.conf`:

   ```
   [Seat:*]
   display-setup-script=/usr/local/bin/redshift.sh
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Another one way is to set up startup command for redshift with manually specified lon:lat like:

```
redshift-gtk -l xx:yy
```

where xx - latitude, yy - longitude

Startup Application Screen:
[image]

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Answer (score 0):

Create the file `~/.xprofile` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10 && redshift -PO 4200 &
```

The [xprofile](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xprofile) is executed at the beginning of the X user session, after you log in to the graphical shell (Unity or Gnome).

The command `redshift -PO 4200` sets the temperature to 4200K.

You can test the script by logging out and then logging in.

Comment: Why sleep 10 seconds?

Comment: @KajMagnus To be effective, redshift should be ran after some other processes finished.