# Is it possible to have f.lux (software that adjusts display's color temperature) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: display, color-management

f.lux is software which adjusts temperature of your display according to time of the day. Is it possible to make f.lux work in Ubuntu 14.04? If so, maybe you can share your knowledge or point me to a guide.

Comment: There is a tool called redshift native to Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/111576/how-do-i-get-redshift-to-start-with-my-computer

Comment: [I don't have enough reputation to comment.] Installing f.lux indicator may not be enough to get f.lux working. Currently the f.lux gui does not necessarily come packaged with xflux. Download the xflux binaries (32 or 64 bit, depending on your architecture) and place the binary in /usr/bin. You can grab xflux from the f.lux website. I'm on 14.04 and am still having trouble with xflux, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: If there is built package available for your Ubuntu series [here](https://launchpad.net/~kilian/+archive/ubuntu/f.lux/+packages), the installation can be done by using the PPA as stated by [karel](http://askubuntu.com/a/493525/304559). If not, [compile it by source](http://askubuntu.com/a/548714/304559). Or else [install `redshift-gtk`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/375700/ppa-404-error-when-installing-flux-on-ubuntu-13-10/579765#579765) from the official repositories.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here is another way I just found. I had to do this way because company firewall won't let me add apt repository no matter what I tried.

1. download source code from author's github

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/xflux-gui/xflux-gui.git
   ```
2. install

   ```
   cd xflux-gui
   sudo python setup.py install
   ```
3. run from command line

   ```
   fluxgui
   ```

[update as of Feb 23 2017] repo is changed

Comment: This suggestion worked perfectly in Ubuntu 14.10. Now, I have f.lux installed and running. Thanks.

Comment: worked for me, except `sudo ./setup.py install` gave me an error so i used `sudo python setup.py install`, also if you do not have it you will need to install python-appindicator... `sudo apt-get install python-appindicator`

Comment: These were all the dependenciesI had to install as well: `sudo apt-get install python-pexpect python-gconf python-appindicator`

Comment: The updated repo is at https://github.com/xflux-gui/xflux-gui and in that page the install instructions were given https://github.com/xflux-gui/xflux-gui#install-instructions

Answer (score 73):

May I suggest [RedShift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/)?

It's more maintained than flu.x, it has more options and it works perfectly with Ubuntu 14.10 x64 and Ubuntu 15.04 x64.

It can be installed from the repositories (12.04, 14.04, and newer):

```
sudo apt-get install redshift redshift-gtk
```

You may optionally create a configuration file for RedShift. It is NOT created automatically, so you'll have to create it using `gedit ~/.config/redshift.conf`.

This is how my `redshift.conf` file looks like:

```
; Global settings for redshift
[redshift]
; Set the day and night screen temperatures
temp-day=4500
temp-night=3500

; Enable/Disable a smooth transition between day and night
; 0 will cause a direct change from day to night screen temperature.
; 1 will gradually increase or decrease the screen temperature
transition=1

; Set the screen brightness. Default is 1.0
;brightness=0.8
; It is also possible to use different settings for day and night since version 1.8.
brightness-day=0.9
brightness-night=0.7
; Set the screen gamma (for all colors, or each color channel individually)
gamma=0.8
;gamma=0.8:0.7:0.8

; Set the location-provider: 'geoclue', 'gnome-clock', 'manual'
; type 'redshift -l list' to see possible values
; The location provider settings are in a different section.
location-provider=geoclue

; Set the adjustment-method: 'randr', 'vidmode'
; type 'redshift -m list' to see all possible values
; 'randr' is the preferred method, 'vidmode' is an older API
; but works in some cases when 'randr' does not.
; The adjustment method settings are in a different section.
adjustment-method=randr

; Configuration of the location-provider:
; type 'redshift -l PROVIDER:help' to see the settings
; ex: 'redshift -l manual:help'
[manual]
; set these values if you've set the location-provider to manual instead of geoclue
;lat=51.522698
;lon=-0.085358

; Configuration of the adjustment-method
; type 'redshift -m METHOD:help' to see the settings
; ex: 'redshift -m randr:help'

[randr]
screen=0
```

If you need to, compiling it manually is also quite easy. Here is the official repository: https://github.com/jonls/redshift

Just make sure that you've installed all the dependencies specified in the `travis.yml` file before running the bootstrap executable file.

Instructions here: https://github.com/jonls/redshift/blob/master/HACKING.md

For Ubuntu 15.04 users: it could be that you won't be able to use redshift because of some missing dependencies. Try to compile it by getting the code directly from github.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libxcb-randr0-dev
./bootstrap
./configure --enable-randr
make
sudo checkinstall
```

...or just `install` if you don't want to use `checkinstall`.
The `libxcb-randr0-dev` package should satisfy the dependency to use randr as an adjustment method. Otherwise try to enable *vidmode* by doing:

```
./configure --enable-vidmode
```

Answer (score 12):

#### Ubuntu 17.10 and later

Starting with GNOME desktop environment 3.24, which was released on March 22, 2017, a new Night Light feature is included that automatically reduces the amount of blue light emitted by screens during certain times of the day. The new feature can be enabled from the display settings. The screen color follows the sunrise/sunset times for your location, but it can also be set to a custom schedule. The Night Light panel indicator shows when the feature is active, and the system menu allows it to be temporarily disabled.

In Ubuntu 17.10, Ubuntu ships with GNOME desktop environment, not Unity, and the Night Light feature is included by default. Night Light works with both X11 and Wayland. To enable Night Light in Ubuntu 17.10 go to *System Settings* -> *Devices* -> *Displays* -> *Night Light* and slide the Night Light slider from OFF to ON. Then configure the schedule settings.

[image]
<sup>**Night Light settings in Ubuntu 17.10**</sup>

The Night Light Slider GNOME Shell Extension provides an easy interface to tweak the temperature of the night light from the notification area of the panel. Be sure to check out the preferences in GNOME Tweak Tool to customize or enable added functionality. You can also easily configure the night light to always be on or to always show the status icon.

---

#### Ubuntu 12.04-17.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/flux
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fluxgui
```

#### Ubuntu 12.04-14.04

Installation is of f.lux in Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 is easily done by adding the PPA for f.lux. Simply type the following in your terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kilian/f.lux
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fluxgui
```

#### Installing xflux daemon terminal program from the official f.lux website

**64-bit**

```
wget -c https://justgetflux.com/linux/xflux64.tgz
tar -xvzf xflux64.tgz
rm -rf xflux64.tgz
sudo cp xflux /usr/bin/
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/xflux
```

**32-bit**

```
wget -c https://justgetflux.com/linux/xflux-pre.tgz
tar -xvzf xflux-pre.tgz
rm -rf xflux-pre.tgz
sudo cp xflux /usr/bin/
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/xflux
```

f.lux GUI can be started from the Dash or from the terminal with the command `fluxgui`. When it is running there is a f.lux icon in the notification area of the panel.

[image]
⠀<sup>**f.lux indicator applet preferences in Xubuntu 14.04**</sup>

Comment: ... and it doesnt work. Before answering the question you should make sure you answer it correctly.
In earlier version (13.04, etc.) it worked, but in 14.04 - it doesn't.

Comment: I installed f.lux in Xubuntu 14.04 and it seems to be working. It added a f.lux icon to the Xubuntu 14.04 Accessories menu and a f.lux applet to the Panel. I don't know if it makes any difference that you're using Unity and I'm not.

Comment: I guess it does since it is a known problem that flux doesn't work in ubuntu 14.04 :/

Comment: I followed @karel's advice and f.lux works fine for me. Running Ubuntu 14.04 and Unity.

Comment: I installed it using the steps above, I entered my location in the configuration window and nothing happened, also after I closed the window I can't get it to open again... killed all the processes related to fluxgui, flux and python still it won't start again and when I try to start it from console it says `fluxgui is already running, exiting` but ps aux doesn't show any process - ubuntu 14.04 - any thoughts?

Comment: @Emi Once you get f.lux configured, the only way that I know of to get the configuration window back again is to use `sudo apt-get purge fluxgui` to remove f.lux and then reinstall f.lux. And if you get the settings wrong, then f.lux won't start. When you reinstall f.lux be careful that you get everything right this time. I know this from personal experience. If there is a better way than this to fix problems with f.lux, then I don't know it.

Comment: If you are considering installing f.lux on a computer with a weak CPU, please note that f.lux takes up a lot of CPU. That was the main reason behind ditching xflux (the X11 edition of the software).

Answer (score 3):

## New Flux app for Ubuntu 15.04+

[image: Flux for Ubuntu]

[Kilian Valkhof's](https://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/linux/flux-for-ubuntu/) repository for Flux does not update anymore, but you can use [Nathan Rennie-Waldock’s](https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/ubuntu/flux) PPA.

Run these commands to install `Flux`:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/flux
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install fluxgui
```

To remove:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove fluxgui
```

---

*Via: [Ubuntu Handbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/03/install-f-lux-in-ubuntu-16-04/)*

Comment: Wait... Just tested this again. It worked for me yesterday, but now it doesn't work anymore. I can start the applet, but no change in screen colour.

Comment: What's your local time? The color automatically changes after sunset

Comment: Yeah, I know. I use f.lux on Windows, OS X, Android, iOS, etc. It straight-up didn't work on Ubuntu tonight. I also tried the "preview" function, which didn't work either.

Comment: That's weird. Using it right now. Try restarting your pc or updating it

Comment: Weird indeed. Especially since it worked yesterday. I did try to restart. I also tried purging the fluxgui and reinstalling. Yeah, I guess I should update.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest [eyesome](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome)?

## eyesome

Eyesome is a bash script running as a deamon and sleeping most of the time 24/7. It automatically adjusts screen brightness (and optionally gamma too) for your laptop display via hardware interface and up to two other monitors using xrandr's software control.

At sunrise (the time is automatically obtained from the internet each day), your screen brightness (and optionally gamma too) is adjusted gradually. The gradual adjustment is defined by you but, 120 minutes works for me. To keep the adjustments unnoticeable set a sleep interval between adjustments. Anywhere between 15 and 60 seconds is probably best and the default is 60.

After sunrise transition is complete, eyesome daemon sleeps many hours until sunset transition starts. I'm using 90 minutes before sunset but you can set any period you like.

Inversely to sunrise transition, the sunset transition gradually decreases screen brightness (and optionally gamma too) so it is unnoticeable.

Note that during nighttime transition gamma may increase. For example Red gamma may be defined as 1.0 during day and 1.2 during night to reduce eye strain. Blue gamma in turn may be defined as 1.0 during day and .8 during night so it will decrease instead.

To reduce resources, eyesome sleeps the entire period between sunset and sunrise. Depending on where you live and the season of the year, the average sleep will be 12 hours.

## Eyesome Setup - Main Menu

To configure eyesome, a main menu is provided:

[image: eyesome main menu.png]

### Edit Configuration - General tab

When you click the ***Edit*** button from the main menu the edit configuration general tab initially appears as shown below.

[image: eyesome configuration general tab.png]

Your country/city name should automatically appear. If necessary you can override it.

### Edit Configuration - Monitor 1 tab

Clicking on Monitor 1 tab above will reveal this panel in my configuration (yours may be different):

[image: eyesome-edit-configuration-monitor-1.png]

Don't be daunted by these settings they are for the most part automatically obtained by eyesome. You will need to set the daytime and night brightness/levels though.

### Edit Configuration - Monitor 3 Tab

Clicking on Monitor 3 Tab reveals this panel in my configuration (yours may be different):

Monitor 2 Tab is not shown because it is a new TV with adaptive brightness and Smart OS. It requires no overrides by Eyesome.

[image]

If after eyesome is installed you attach a different monitor to your system you may have to enter the `xrandr` monitor name.

### Eyesome Setup - 5 second test

From the main menu you can test your daytime and nighttime brightness and gamma settings for 5 seconds by clicking the ***Daytime*** and ***Nighttime*** buttons respectively. You can change the duration of the test from 5 seconds up to 20 seconds from the Edit Configuration - General Tab.

Here's what the 5 second Nighttime test looks like:

[image: eyesome nighttime test.gif]

## Unusual event handling

Assume you suspend your laptop when it's morning before work and the screen is at full dim. You come home after work when the sun is high in the sky and open your laptop. The screen is so dim you can't read it.

To address this scenario a systemd control file is provided:

- `/etc/systemd/system-sleep/systemd-wake-eyesome` control file is called whenever the system suspends or resumes.
- The control file calls the bash script `/usr/local/bin/wake-eyesome.sh` to reset brightness to full and then sleep until sunset transition.

You are watching a movie on your external TV at night and close your laptop lid for better viewing. Ubuntu / Lightdm / xrandr takes a few seconds and then resets your external TV to full full brightness. OUCH to your eyes.

To address this scenario an acpi event control file is provided:

- `/etc/acpi/event/lid-event-eyesome` control file is called whenever the laptop lid is opened or closed.
- The control file calls the bash script `/etc/acpi/acpi-lid-eyesome.sh` to handle the lid opening and closing.
- In turn the eyesome bash script calls `/usr/local/bin/wake-eyesome.sh` to reset brightness for nighttive viewing and then sleeps until sunset transition.

  Suspend/Lid close/Test brightness/power off/hotplug

## Summary

Eyesome can be downloaded from: https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome

This program was just released in September 2018 so please let me know if you find any problems or have suggestions for improvement.

The documentation phase is just starting so don't hesitate to ask any questions. Your questions may even result in documentation improvements.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 20.04, you don't need to install any external packages. It has inbuilt package named xgamma.
You can use it as follows:

```
xgamma 0.5
```

or you can adjust only blue color:

```
xgamma -bgamma 0.5
```

Its value can vary from 0 to 1.