# ./setup.py: command not found

Tags: 14.04, display, temperature

I followed steps from here 
[Flux for ubuntu 14.04 - possible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493507/flux-for-ubuntu-14-04-possible)
to install flux but I am getting an error like

> ./setup.py: command not found

please guide me soon. Thank you

Comment: Did you change directory doing cd f.lux-indicator-applet before sudo ./setup.py install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can install f.lux using a PPA -

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kilian/f.lux`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install fluxgui`

The PPA has been updated to work with Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr.