# What is (the technical name of) Ubuntu night light mode

Tags: 20.04, brightness

Ubuntu now has by default a night light mode, so you don't have to use redshift or flux.

What is the name of it ? I mean, technical name, like the corresponding package. Could I install and use it on another distro ?

Comment: It's part of GNOME - https://www.gnome.org/news/2017/03/gnome-3-24-released/attachment/night-light/  (so it'll already be on GNOME desktops if a modern enough version)

Comment: The GNOME component is called [Night Light](https://askubuntu.com/a/493525/)

Comment: Thanks. As a part of gnome, I guess it is not usable with other desktop environment... So I will just use f.lux instead :/

Comment: In response to the closure of the question : The whole question was exactly to NOT use f.lux but ubuntu Night Light instead...